# R Key Value Pair like Hastable

Tags: r, dynamic, collections, hashtable

I'm new to R Programming, can you please help to solve two scenarios ?

1. How can I automate n number of attribute and value such as Attribute_1_Name, Attribute_1_Value... , Attribute_n_Name, Attribute_n_Value and get a final result as shown below?

   ```
   result = cbind.data.frame(
   PFA_Unique_Identifier,
   Fund_Unique_Identifier,
   VaR_Type,

   Attribute_1_Name,
   Attribute_1_Value,
   Attribute_2_Name,
   Attribute_2_Value, .............., Attribute_n_Name, Attribute_n_Value, varValueRaw )
   ```
2. How can I create hash table of name/value pairs and automate below piece of code in R.

   ```
   if (attributeCount == 0)
     {
       Attribute_1_Value = Attribute_1_Name = NA
       Attribute_2_Value = Attribute_2_Name = NA
     }
     else if (attributeCount == 1)
     {
       Attribute_1_Name = rep(attributeNames,n)
       Attribute_1_Value = attributeFilter
       Attribute_2_Value = Attribute_2_Name = NA
     }
     else if (attributeCount == 2)
     {
       Attribute_1_Name = rep(attributeNames[1],n)
       Attribute_1_Value = attributeFilter[,1]
       Attribute_2_Name = rep(attributeNames[2],n)
       Attribute_2_Value = attributeFilter[,2]
     }
     else
     {
       stop("It has not been implemented for attributes filter more than 2")
     }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand what you are asking, but I think that you are looking for [FAQ 7.21](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f).

The most important part of that answer is the final couple of sentences where it says that it is simplest to put things into a list.  If you really need the keys/names to be hashed then you can use an environment instead of a list, the interface is almost identical but environments use hashing where last I remember lists do a linear look up (you probably won't notice a difference unless you have several thousand objects in your list or environment).

Are you just trying to create a vector or the strings? (remember a list is different from a vector).

If so, here is one way:

```
n <- 3
outstring <- c(
  "PFA_Unique_Identifier", "Fund_Unique_Identifier", "VaR_Type",
  rbind(
    sprintf("Attribute_%d_Name", seq_len(n)),
    sprintf("Attribute_%d_Value", seq_len(n))
  ),
  "varValueRaw"
)

outstring
```

If you want that as a single string then do:

```
paste(outstring, collapse=", ")
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify little more what I'm looking for. How can I get this list Dynamically? "PFA_Unique_Identifier,
Fund_Unique_Identifier,
VaR_Type,

Attribute_1_Name,
Attribute_1_Value,
Attribute_2_Name,
Attribute_2_Value, .............., Attribute_n_Name, Attribute_n_Value, varValueRaw"

Comment: @Partha, I have added an example above, is that what you want?

Comment: Greg - That's perfect. that's what I was looking for. One more question for you. When I try to use that string in cbind.data.frame I'm getting an error. Do you know how I can fix it ?  This is the Error : "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 0"   
  ttibuteColumns <- paste(outstring, collapse=", ")
  result = cbind.data.frame(attibuteColumns)

Comment: @Partha, you are moving in the direction of `fortune(106)` (and `fortune(181)`).  Better is to do something like: `do.call('cbind.data.frame', mget(outstring))`.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much Greg. Perfect solution. :)